# Groovy: CREATE VIEW from script fails with 'create view should be the first'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, groovy

I create views in SQL Server DBs with following SQL script from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
use DB_1
go

if exists (select * from sysobjects where name='view_name' and xtype='V')
    drop view view_name
go

create view view_name as (
select l.* from table_name l join (select col_1, col_2 from table_name group by   col_2, col_1 having col_1=max(col_1)) m on (l.col_2=m.col_2and l.col_1 = m.col_1) 
)
go

use DB_2
go

if exists (select * from sysobjects where name='view_name' and xtype='V')
    drop view view_name
go

create view view_name as (
select l.* from table_name l join (select col_1, col_2 from table_name group by col_2, col_1 having col_1=max(col_1)) m on (l.col_2=m.col_2 and l.col_1 = m.col_1) 
)
go

if exists (select * from sysobjects where name='view_name_2' and xtype='V')
drop view view_name_2
go


create view view_name_2 as (
select l.* from table_name_2 l join (select col_1, col_2 from table_name_2 group by col_2, col_1 having col_1=max(col_1)) m on (l.col_2=m.col_2 and l.col_1 = m.col_1) 
)
go
```

I have some Groovy scripts to execute others SQL scripts, so I simply tried to execute this one in full analogy with others:

```
Sql.withInstance( ...connection_params... ){
    it.execute( ( new File( 'Script.sql' ) ).text )
}
```

Where Script.sql is SQL query mentioned above with small modifications (without 'GO' statements).

I get following error for this Groovy script during execution:

```
... create view should be the first in query batch ...
```

I do not understand this error. What should I correct in the script to execute this?

I tried to create some workarounds and got the following one working for me:

```
Sql.withInstance( ...connection_params... ){ oSQL ->
        ( new File( 'Script_2.sql' ) ).eachLine{ oSQL.execute( it ) }
    }
```

Where Script_2.sql is light modification of Script.sql: I removed empty lines and transform multiline queries to single line ones.

But I want to understand my root cause. Please help me in it!

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know anything about Groovy. However, there are certain commands within SQL that should occur first. One of these is "create view". "GO" is a batch separator. So if you have multiple SQL statements that you are processing at one time, and one of them is "create view" it must be the first - or separated from the batch by "go". You may find this arbitrary, however there are good reasons behind this. In most cases its locking of objects and resources in general. Here is a discussion https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34654/sql-server-must-be-first-statement-in-query-batch-what-and-why The reason is probably bound up with how SQL handles the various objects and needs to maintain consistency across transactions and the like. You get many very good things with MS SQL, but there are some limits and this is one of them. Just need to work around it.

Comment: Ian, Thanks! Got it! In my workaround I call statements one a time. And I cannot run script with GO from Groovy. So, Looks like it is not my issue. Just MS SQL Server rule.